# Angular order by numbers with decimals

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-filters

I have the following array:

```
[
 {volume:49, number: 1}, 
 {volume:48, number: 3}, 
 {volume:4,  number: 1}, 
 {volume:4,  number: 4}, 
 {volume:1,  number: 1}, 
 {volume:9,  number: 2}, 
 {volume:5,  number: 1}, 
 {volume:5,  number: 2}
]
```

My current filtering is ordering the numbers

```
[9.2, 5.1, 5.2, 49.1, 48.3, 4.4, 4.1, 1.1 ]
```

Here is my ng-repeat:

```
<a ng-repeat="item in issueList | orderBy:['-volume','-number']">
    <div>
       {{ item.volume }}.{{ item.number }}
    </div>
</a>
```

Is my current logic incorrect? It seems like the ordering for volume is looking at the first number, somehow resulting in 9 and 5 coming before 49

Comment: shouldn't it be `orderBy:['-volume','-number']`? `volume` is a number not object? EDIT: Created fiddle: just using `-volume` instead of `-volume.number` and it works. http://jsfiddle.net/cywm00jx/

Comment: Yes, what ste2425 said - are you sure thats the code you're using.  I tried to recreate and I got .4 .3 .2 .2 .1 .1 .1 .1 (with all the volume.numbers being undefined).  If you replace 'volume.number' with just 'volume' it should work.

Comment: that was my typo, I've edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like your numbers are treated as strings, that is why they are not sorted as expected.

Try to make them integers in an implicit way:

```
$scope.items = [
  {volume:'49', number: 1}, 
  {volume:'48', number: 3}, 
  {volume:'4',  number: 1}, 
  {volume:'4',  number: 4}, 
  {volume:'1',  number: 1}, 
  {volume:'9',  number: 2}, 
  {volume:'5',  number: 1}, 
  {volume:'5',  number: 2}
];
angular.forEach($scope.items, function (item) {
    console.log(item);
    item.volume = +item.volume;
});
```

Comment: That was it. Thank you! I ended up making a filter:
app.filter('num', function() {
    return function(input) {
      return parseInt(input, 10);
    };
});

using is orderBy:['-volume | num','-number']"